# Android: Cannot display retrieved POJOs from Firebase to GridView in Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Intro: *I am trying to build an android app that displays info about books (using Google books API).I have recently added firebase to the app.
At this moment I can log in or register to the app,I can search for books (with search view) and I have added a button for every book listed in the ListView that is created from the query.I added functionality to the button as it follows: the button (if pressed) should add the current book(in the Listview) to FireBase.*

My next step is to **retrieve and display** all the books(BookObjects) added by users in another activity called **CatalogActivity**

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);
  GridView catalogListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.CatalogGridList);
  mCatalogActivity = this;
  final List<BookObject> books = new ArrayList<BookObject>();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
    databaseReference.child("books").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                BookObject book = child.getValue(BookObject.class);
                books.add(book);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    CatalogAdapter catalogAdapter = new CatalogAdapter(this, books);
    catalogListView.setAdapter(catalogAdapter);

    }
 }
```

For better understanding this is the **Firebase Data tab:**
[image]

(In app) When I click on **CatalogActivity the activity layout is empty**(the gridview has either no items to display or they are empty).

I have used debugging with break-points and I got to the following conclusions:

-database instance and reference are obtained correctly

-snapshot of all BookObjects is obtained correctly (`dataSnapshot`)

-all child snapshot (`child`) are obtained.

-Books (4 books in this case) are added to `books`

**Then why aren't the books displayed?**(the books are set in a custom Adapter and should be displayed)

**Note**:*I tried commenting out the firebase retrieveing data code and I have added some hardcoded book objects. Those were displayed correctly so therefore the issue is not with my custom Adapter.anyways I will post the gist below for any more info*

Gist of POJO `BookObject` class:[BookObject](https://gist.github.com/catalinghita8/d7d659d157e78e3dd099584a7060fd5a)

Gist of custom Adapter Catalogadapter class : [CatalogAdapter](https://gist.github.com/catalinghita8/eb038622cde1de03787fef35aa2d86b7)

*Any help is highly appreciated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are setting your `Adapter` before data is fetched from Firebase. To fix that, you should set your adapter inside `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` callback.

```
@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
        for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
            BookObject book = child.getValue(BookObject.class);
            books.add(book);
        }
        CatalogAdapter catalogAdapter = new CatalogAdapter(this, books);
        catalogListView.setAdapter(catalogAdapter);
    }
```

You can also set an Adapter the way you are doing, an invoke `catalogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` within Firebase callback.

Comment: Thank you for your help.Now it's displaying the data perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, please use this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
databaseReference.child("books").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<BookObject> books = new ArrayList<BookObject>();

        Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
        for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
            BookObject book = child.getValue(BookObject.class);
            books.add(book);
        }
        CatalogAdapter catalogAdapter = new CatalogAdapter(this, books);
        catalogListView.setAdapter(catalogAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

As you probably see, i have moved the declaration of the `ArrayList` inside the `onDataChange()` method, because otherwise is null. Because the `ArrayList` does contain information only inside the `onDataChange()`, setting the adapter should take place also there.